# Is there any possibility to have two BaseURL WebHostUrl in ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

We are running AppService in cloud. The WebHostUrl url is stored in web.config file and assigned the url in application start event as like below.

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig { 
    WebHostUrl = baseUrl,
);
```

We have requirement to configure two baseurl in servicestack. That means, the appservice can be accessed either of two url.

https://example1.com/appservice

or

https://example2.com/appservice.

Please suggest how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify the `BaseUrl` ServiceStack automatically uses the URL for the incoming Request.

Basically you don't want to define these URLs in ServiceStack, the 2 virtual hosts should be handled by an external reverse proxy like nginx. The nginx/rsync deployment docs shows an example for how to [configure a virtual host to use an Nginx reverse proxy](https://docs.servicestack.net/netcore-deploy-rsync#setup-nginx). You'd just need to create 2 virtual hosts for each domain you want to support.

Comment: Thanks mythz for immediate response. Actually the appservice is hosted in Azure cloud. Configured with slot and controlled by traffic manager. The release is first moved to staging slot and traffic is slow redirected to current prod slot to stag slot. Once the traffic reached to 90% then current stag slot become prod slot.

Comment: Actually the appservice is hosted in Azure cloud and Configured with slots which is controlled by traffic manager. The code release is first moved to the staging slot and traffic is slow redirected to current prod slot to stag slot. Once the traffic reached to 90% then current stag slot become prod slot. Since both slot is configured with DNS name (example.com),  We could not test our changesin the stag slot. Because we dont have control which request is redirected to stag slot by traffic manager. Is there any way to config two url in service stack? appreciate your response.

Comment: @RajaseharR An app cannot support multiple base urls, the WebHostUrl is used when you want to override the incoming request URL, if you want to use the incoming request url you should not configure `WebHostUrl`. Unless your hosting solution can support reverse proxying to multiple virtual hosts, you would need to host multiple instances.